# PHP export with empty content

Tags: php, export-to-csv

I'm having a problem here. I wanted to retrieve all the data from mysql database and export it. However, the exported csv file contains nothing. Please help me.

```
if(isset($_POST['export'])){
$filename = 'applicants '.date('m-d-Y').'.csv'; 
$tableName="applicants";
$sql=mysql_query("select * from applicants");
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($sql);
mysql_data_seek($sql, 0);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");
$seperator="";
$comma="";
$tableName="applicants";

foreach($row as $name => $value)
{
    if($name==""){
        $name=" ";
    }
    $seperator .= $comma . '' .str_replace('','""','"'.$name.'"');
    $comma = ",";

}
$seperator .="\n";
fputs($fp,$seperator);
mysql_data_seek($sql, 0);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $seperator="";
    $comma="";
    foreach($row as $name => $value)
    {
        $seperator .= $comma . '' .str_replace('','""','"'.$value.'"');
        $comma = ",";   
    }
    $seperator .="\n";
    fputs($fp,$seperator);
}
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Every time I see somebody using a homebrew csv export rather than [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) I want to scream

Comment: But there's nothing here creates an SQL query or executes one

Comment: Oops, Don't understand why some codes went missing.

        $sql=mysql_query("select * from applicants");
 $num_rows=mysql_num_rows($sql);
 mysql_data_seek($sql, 0);
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
 $fp = fopen($filename,"w");
 $seperator="";
 $comma="";

That are the codes after the $tableName="applicants";

Comment: There you go. Thanks!

Comment: `str_replace('','""','"'.$value.'"');` seriously? What is this supposed to do? The problem with Homebrew is trying to understand what you're doing

Comment: That thing adds (" ") to every field. So the address fields that contain comma won't be separated as well.

Answer (score 0):

**here is simple methos to do that ...make changes according  to you**

```
   // output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('mysqlColumnName1', 'mysqlColumnName2', 'mysqlColumnName3'));

// fetch the data
mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('database');
$rows = mysql_query('SELECT field1,field2,field3 FROM table');

// loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) 
            fputcsv($output, $row);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sending a `Content-Disposition` header does not automatically attach the file. You should include it manually, e.g.

```
// ...
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
fclose($fp);
echo file_get_contents($filename);
```

Alternatively, you can use `fopen('php://output', 'w');` as the Harsh's answer suggests.

Also, really, do use `fputcsv`.